# notifyDataSetChanged() and getview() in for loop

Tags: android, gridview, adaptor

I am using GridView,ImageView and BaseAdapter to display 80 images as the code in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html. 
in

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        (code data changes)
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

gridview will refresh, getview is called. but if I add a for loop in as such

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

            (code data changes)
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

gridview will not refresh, and I find getview is not called. why? what should I do if I want to use a loop to refresh gridview?

Comment: Please format your code next time, that was unreadable

Comment: As for your question-  was it not called at all, or not until the loop was finished?  In general you only want to call notifty after ALL changes are done.  Notifying more frequently than that would be pointless, as the list can't get redrawn until your UI thread returns to the event loop anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe Sechan. It was indeed called after the loop. what should I use if I want to refresh the gridview frequently?

Comment: Just that-  call notifyDataSetChanged once when you're done with the updates.  Unless you're doing something insane computationally, that will update it faster than you can see.  And if you are, then you ought to be using a thread.